# How to get product root category name or ID using product ID in magento 2.2.6?

Tags: product, category, category-attribute, magento2.2.6

I am working on magento 2.2.6

I am using file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product/View.php

In this, I am trying to get root category name or ID of product using product id in function i**nitProductLayout()**...

My constructor code is as below:

```
   class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * List of catalog product session message groups
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $messageGroups;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * Catalog product
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product
     */
    protected $_catalogProduct = null;

    /**
     * Catalog design
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design
     */
    protected $_catalogDesign;

    /**
     * Catalog session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_catalogSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator
     */
    protected $categoryUrlPathGenerator;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils
     */
    private $string;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
     */
    private $categoryFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator
     * @param array $messageGroups
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils|null $string
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
        array $messageGroups = [],
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string = null,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->_catalogDesign = $catalogDesign;
        $this->_catalogProduct = $catalogProduct;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->messageGroups = $messageGroups;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator = $categoryUrlPathGenerator;
        $this->string = $string ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils::class);
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Add meta information from product to layout
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    private function preparePageMetadata(ResultPage $resultPage, $product)
    {
        $pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();

        $metaTitle = $product->getMetaTitle();
        $pageConfig->setMetaTitle($metaTitle);
        $pageConfig->getTitle()->set($metaTitle ?: $product->getName());

        $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
        $currentCategory = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
        if ($keyword) {
            $pageConfig->setKeywords($keyword);
        } elseif ($currentCategory) {
            $pageConfig->setKeywords($product->getName());
        }

        $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
        if ($description) {
            $pageConfig->setDescription($description);
        } else {
            $pageConfig->setDescription($this->string->substr(strip_tags($product->getDescription()), 0, 255));
        }

        if ($this->_catalogProduct->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
            $pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, ['_ignore_category' => true]),
                'canonical',
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
            );
        }

        $pageMainTitle = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
        if ($pageMainTitle) {
            $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($product->getName());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Init layout for viewing product page
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param null|\Magento\Framework\DataObject $params
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function initProductLayout(ResultPage $resultPage, $product, $params = null)
    {
        $settings = $this->_catalogDesign->getDesignSettings($product);
        $pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();

        if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
            $this->_catalogDesign->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
        }

        // Apply custom page layout
        if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
            $pageConfig->setPageLayout($settings->getPageLayout());
        }

        $urlSafeSku = rawurlencode($product->getSku());

        // Load default page handles and page configurations
        if ($params && $params->getBeforeHandles()) {
            foreach ($params->getBeforeHandles() as $handle) {
                $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $product->getTypeId()], $handle, false);
                $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku], $handle);
            }
        }

        $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $product->getTypeId()], null, false);
        $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku]);

        if ($params && $params->getAfterHandles()) {
            foreach ($params->getAfterHandles() as $handle) {
                $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $product->getTypeId()], $handle, false);
                $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku], $handle);
            }
        }

        // Apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
        $update = $resultPage->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates();
        if ($layoutUpdates) {
            if (is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                foreach ($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                    $update->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                }
            }
        }

        $currentCategory = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');

        $controllerClass = $this->_request->getFullActionName();
        if ($controllerClass != 'catalog-product-view') {
            $pageConfig->addBodyClass('catalog-product-view');
        }

        $productId = $product->getData('entity_id');


        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
        $categoryCollection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',['finset' => categoryIds])->addFieldToFilter('level', 1); // Inject \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory in contructor
        print_r($categoryCollection->getData());exit;

        $pageConfig->addBodyClass('product-' . $product->getUrlKey());
        if ($currentCategory instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category) {
            $pageConfig->addBodyClass('categorypath-' . $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($currentCategory))
                ->addBodyClass('category-' . $currentCategory->getUrlKey());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Prepares product view page - inits layout and all needed stuff
     *
     * $params can have all values as $params in \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product - initProduct().
     * Plus following keys:
     *   - 'buy_request' - \Magento\Framework\DataObject holding buyRequest to configure product
     *   - 'specify_options' - boolean, whether to show 'Specify options' message
     *   - 'configure_mode' - boolean, whether we're in Configure-mode to edit product configuration
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage
     * @param int $productId
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller
     * @param null|\Magento\Framework\DataObject $params
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View
     */
    public function prepareAndRender(ResultPage $resultPage, $productId, $controller, $params = null)
    {
        /**
         * Remove default action handle from layout update to avoid its usage during processing of another action,
         * It is possible that forwarding to another action occurs, e.g. to 'noroute'.
         * Default action handle is restored just before the end of current method.
         */
        $defaultActionHandle = $resultPage->getDefaultLayoutHandle();
        $handles = $resultPage->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();
        if (in_array($defaultActionHandle, $handles)) {
            $resultPage->getLayout()->getUpdate()->removeHandle($resultPage->getDefaultLayoutHandle());
        }

        if (!$controller instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\ViewInterface) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Bad controller interface for showing product')
            );
        }
        // Prepare data
        $productHelper = $this->_catalogProduct;
        if (!$params) {
            $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        }

        // Standard algorithm to prepare and render product view page
        $product = $productHelper->initProduct($productId, $controller, $params);
        if (!$product) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(__('Product is not loaded'));
        }

        $buyRequest = $params->getBuyRequest();
        if ($buyRequest) {
            $productHelper->prepareProductOptions($product, $buyRequest);
        }

        if ($params->hasConfigureMode()) {
            $product->setConfigureMode($params->getConfigureMode());
        }

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_controller_product_view', ['product' => $product]);

        $this->_catalogSession->setLastViewedProductId($product->getId());

        if (in_array($defaultActionHandle, $handles)) {
            $resultPage->addDefaultHandle();
        }

        $this->initProductLayout($resultPage, $product, $params);
        $this->preparePageMetadata($resultPage, $product);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 0):

To get root category name and id from product, try below way

```
public function __construct(
    ------
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    ------
) {
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}
public function getCategory() 
{
   $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
   $categoryCollection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',['finset' => categoryIds])->addFieldToFilter('level', 1); 
   echo"<pre>";print_r($categoryCollection->getData());exit;
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get the meaning of this.   Inject \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory....  How to inject this in constructor...

Comment: Please check I updated the answer

Comment: I have updated a constructor with your code ... but sorry there is no out put after print

Comment: Can you please update your question. so that I can see what exactly you did. Please update with whole class.

Comment: Hi Ramkishan .. please check i have updated a question...  Same thing you are saying right?  on this i am getting bank page... My error display settings are on

Comment: Please update with whole class, You only updated with constructor.

Comment: ok sure........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84941/discussion-between-rk1990-and-ramkishan).